# Using a firefox keyword for Wolfram|Alpha can't cope with plus signs

Tags: firefox, search, wolfram-alpha

I've got a firefox keyword ("alpha") to search Wolfram|Alpha, but if I type something like "alpha 1+1" then Wolfram|Alpha will search for "1 1"; the plus sign gets eaten en route

Luckily for me this problem was found and solve by [this guy.](http://somethingemporium.com/2009/05/using-wolframalpha-as-a-firefox-keyword-search-search-google-use) Sadly his solution opens the search in the current tab, is there a way I can alter the Javascript to open in a new tab instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surrounding window.open with void() opens in a new tab without changing the current window's content.

```
javascript:void(window.open("http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="+encodeURIComponent("%s")));
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the javascript for a bit I have decided that the answer is "no".

While you can get it to open WA in a new tab with

```
javascript:window.open("http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="+encodeURIComponent("%s"));
```

it replaces the current window's content with `[Object Window]` which is just plain annoying.

Your best bet may be to install the [Open Bookmarks In New Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-bookmarks-in-new-tab/) add-on for firefox.

Comment: That's the same answer I came to. Ah, well. If no-one has a better answer I'll accept yours. Thanks for the link too!